# Select hours from one table, but subtract hours from another where conditions exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

using SQL Server and not sure if blanking or trying to do something I've never done before!

So to simplify, I'm doing a Select query for rostering. I have 2 tables:

```
[dbo].[LeaveBalances]
[PrimaryKey]    [Employee]    [LeaveType]    [AsAtDate]    [Balance]
1               100000        ANN            2017-10-23    10
2               100000        SIC            2017-10-23    16

[dbo].[P_R]
[PrimaryKey]    [Employee]    [ShiftDate]    [LeaveType]    [Hrs]
1               100000        2017-10-21     ANN            5
2               100000        2017-10-24     ANN            2
3               100000        2017-10-25     SIC            7
4               123456        2017-10-25     ANN            8
```

The result I want for the query to get the leave balances, net of anything taken after the [AsAtDate], is:

```
[Employee]    [LeaveType]    [AsAtDate]    [Balance]
100000        ANN            2017-10-23    8
100000        SIC            2017-10-23    9
```

So the 2017-10-21 leave taken will be ignored because it's before the date, and the employee 123456 leave will be ignored because it's a different employee, but the other two will be subtracted from the corresponding leave type balances.
The query I've got so far is:

```
SELECT [Employee]
    ,[LeaveType]
    ,[AsAtDate]
    ,[Balance] -
        (SELECT SUM([Hrs]) FROM [dbo].[P_R] WHERE [Employee] = 100000)
        AS [Balance]
FROM [dbo].[LeaveBalances]
WHERE [Employee] = 100000
```

But obviously that's going so subtract all the [Hrs] values for employee 100000 from every leave type, regardless of [P_R] leave type or date. How do I incorporate in those other conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to come up with a solution that seems to work, no idea which method would be most efficient, though, but this one seems elegant enough:

```
SELECT [LB].[Employee]
      ,[LB].[LeaveType]
      ,[LB].[AsAtDate]
      ,[LB].[Balance] - 
          SUM(CASE WHEN [R].[LeaveType] = [LB].[LeaveType] 
          AND [R].[ShiftDate] > [LB].[AsAtDate] 
          THEN [R].[Hrs] ELSE 0 END) [Balance]
  FROM [dbo].[LeaveBalances] [LB]
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[P_R] [R] ON [LB].[Employee] = [R].[Employee]
  WHERE [LB].[Employee] = 100000 AND NOT [LB].[Entitlement] = 0
  GROUP BY [LB].[LeaveType]
      ,[LB].[Employee]
      ,[LB].[AsAtDate]
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to select all `LeaveBalances` records and sum hours of `P_R`. You can do this in a subquery in the `SELECT` clause:

```
select
  employee,
  leavetype,
  asatdate,
  balance - (select sum(hrs) from dbo.p_r p where p.employee = b.employee
                                              and p.leavetype = b.leavetype
                                              and p.shiftdate > b.asatdate
            ) as balance
from dbo.leavebalances b
order by employee, leavetype;
```

Or move the subquery to your `FROM` clause with `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select
  employee,
  leavetype,
  asatdate,
  balance - coalesce(sums.total, 0) as balance
from leavebalances b
outer apply
(
  select sum(hrs) as total
  from p_r p
  where p.employee = b.employee
    and p.leavetype = b.leavetype
    and p.shiftdate > b.asatdate
) sums
order by employee, leavetype;
```

Comment: Curiosity: is that mySQL syntax?

Comment: @dya: The first is standard SQL and should work in about every DBMS including MySQL. As to the second query I am pretty sure this is not standard SQL. I think in standard SQL you would write this a little different using the `LATERAL` keyword. As far as I know `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY` were introduced in T-SQL (SQL-Server) and are supported by Oracle 12c, too, but not in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work out the following query.  In the CTE below, I aggregate the number of sick and annual days spent by each employees after the `AsAtDate` specified in the `LeaveBalances` table.  Note that I had to do a distinct select on `LeaveBalances` to isolate this cutoff date for each employee, implying that your data is not normalized.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.[Employee], t1.[LeaveType], SUM(t1.[Hrs]) AS [Hrs]
    FROM [dbo].[P_R] t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT [Employee], [AsAtDate]
        FROM [dbo].[LeaveBalances]
    ) t2
        ON t1.[Employee] = t2.[Employee]
    WHERE t1.[ShiftDate] > t2.[AsAtDate]
    GROUP BY t1.[Employee], t1.[LeaveType]
)

SELECT
    t1.[Employee], t1.[LeaveType], t1.[AsAtDate],
    t1.[Balance] - COALESCE(t2.[Hrs], 0) AS [Balance]
FROM [dbo].[LeaveBalances] t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.[Employee] = t2.[Employee] AND
       t1.[LeaveType] = t2.[LeaveType];
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: if there's another LeaveType that doesn't have records in P_R, Balance will be Null. just saying... :)

Comment: We can use coalesce in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
This Can be achive by Using CTE
BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LeaveBalances]([ID] INT,   [Employee] NVARCHAR(255),   [LeaveType] NVARCHAR(6) ,  [AsAtDate] DATETIME,   [Balance] INT)
CREATE TABLE[dbo].[P_R](ID INT,[Employee]NVARCHAR(255),    [ShiftDate]  DATETIME,   [LeaveType] NVARCHAR(6) ,  [Hrs] INT)

    INSERT INTO LeaveBalances
    SELECT 1,'100000','ANN','2017-10-23',10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'100000','SIC','2017-10-23',16


    INSERT INTO P_R
    SELECT 1,'100000','2017-10-21','ANN',5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'100000','2017-10-24','ANN', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 ,'100000','2017-10-25','SIC', 7 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'123456','2017-10-25','ANN',8

;WITH CTE  AS
 ( 

    SELECT DISTINCT a.Employee , a.LeaveType , a.AsAtDate , a.Balance
    FROM LeaveBalances a INNER JOIN  P_R P ON a.Employee=P.Employee 
    WHERE p.ShiftDate>a.AsAtDate 
    GROUP BY a.Employee , a.LeaveType , a.AsAtDate , a.Balance,p.Hrs

 )
 SELECT a.Employee , a.LeaveType , a.AsAtDate , a.Balance-b.Hrs Balance
 FROM CTE  a
 INNER JOIN P_R b ON a.Employee=b.Employee AND a.LeaveType=b.LeaveType
  WHERE b.ShiftDate > a.AsAtDate 
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #LeaveBalances([ID] INT,   [Employee] NVARCHAR(255),   [LeaveType] NVARCHAR(6) ,  [AsAtDate] DATETIME,   [Balance] INT)
CREATE TABLE #P_R(ID INT,[Employee]NVARCHAR(255),    [ShiftDate]  DATETIME,   [LeaveType] NVARCHAR(6) ,  [Hrs] INT)

    INSERT INTO #LeaveBalances
    SELECT 1,'100000','ANN','2017-10-23',10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'100000','SIC','2017-10-23',16

    INSERT INTO #P_R
    SELECT 1,'100000','2017-10-21','ANN',5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'100000','2017-10-24','ANN', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 ,'100000','2017-10-25','SIC', 7 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'123456','2017-10-25','ANN',8;

;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT  LBS.Employee,LBS.LeaveType,LBS.AsAtDate,LBS.Balance,#P_R.Hrs,
     ROW_NUMBER()OVER(
       PARTITION BY LBS.Employee,LBS.LeaveType 
       ORDER BY LBS.LeaveType,#P_R.ShiftDate DESC
                   ) AS RN 
    FROM #LeaveBalances AS LBS INNER JOIN #P_R 
        ON (LBS.Employee=#P_R.Employee) 
             AND
              (LBS.LeaveType=#P_R.LeaveType)
              )

SELECT Employee,LeaveType,CAST(AsAtDate AS DATE) AS AsAtDate,
       SUM(Balance-Hrs)over(PARTITION BY Employee,LeaveType ORDER BY LeaveType) AS Balance
        from CTE WHERE RN=1;
------------------------------------------
Employee    LeaveType   AsAtDate    Balance
---------------------------------------------
100000  ANN 2017-10-23  8
100000  SIC 2017-10-23  9
```